# Exchange account will not connect through Outlook, OWA, ActiveSync after event

Tags: exchange

Earlier today, we had an event where Exchange stopped responding or processing mail.  Clients would connect and disconnect, perpetually.   We tracked this down to a corrupted queue folder.   Once we fixed this everything began returning to normal however, about 1% of our mailboxes (including mine) flat out will not accept a connection.   It acts as though the server is not there but I do see RPC errors in the "RPC Client Access Logs".

I can't make heads or tails of it and I can't find any pattern among those affected.

I'd be seriously, grateful for any help or direction someone could lend!

Comment: Hi, first, did you rebooted ? as it seem stuck connections left

Comment: `I do see RPC errors in the "RPC Client Access Logs".` - Maybe share those errors with us?

Answer (score 2):

We resolved this.

I definitely tried rebooting which did not resolve

@joeqwerty - That would seem logical to include the errors, yeah?    I'm sorry.  I was flustered at the time but did resolve this.   Logs also reported a quarantine issue.  After following that rabbit hole, I found that all the affected accounts (and some that had not been reported) were in quarantine.   After correcting, everyone is now back to normal.

Thank you for anytime spent on this!

Comment: Glad to see it is resolved.Thanks for the sharing!

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it.